# TYPO3-Problem with major-upgrade via composer

Tags: composer-php, typo3

I'm making my first steps with the composer and have tried to make an Upgrade from Vs. 10.x auf 11.x
Sadly this error is produced and I dont know how to fix it:

```
    Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires typo3/cms-core ^11.5, found typo3/cms-core[v11.5.0, ..., v11.5.32] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
Problem 2
    - Root composer.json requires typo3/cms-extbase ^11.5, found typo3/cms-extbase[v11.5.0, ..., v11.5.32] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 3
    - Root composer.json requires typo3/cms-backend ^11.5, found typo3/cms-backend[v11.5.0, ..., v11.5.32] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 4
```

and so on.

Can someone help me with this?

I have tried this:

```
composer update "typo3/cms-core:11.5.32" --dry-run

Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires typo3/cms-core ^10.4 || 11.*, found typo3/cms-core[v10.4.0, ..., v10.4.37, v11.0.0, ..., v11.5.32] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - typo3/cms-base-distribution is locked to version v10.4.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - typo3/cms-base-distribution v10.4.3 requires typo3/cms-core ^10.4.0 -> found typo3/cms-core[v10.4.0, ..., v10.4.37] but it conflicts with your temporary update constraint (typo3/cms-core:11.5.32).
  Problem 3
    - typo3/cms-extbase is locked to version v10.4.37 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - typo3/cms-extbase v10.4.37 requires typo3/cms-core 10.4.37 -> found typo3/cms-core[v10.4.37] but it conflicts with your temporary update constraint (typo3/cms-core:11.5.32).
```

what do I have to do?

btw: composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-base-distribution": "^10.4",
        "typo3/cms-core": "^10.4 || 11.*",
        "typo3/cms-extbase": "^10.4 || 11.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "typo3/class-alias-loader": true,
            "typo3/cms-composer-installers": true
             
        }
    }
}
```

check it out with:

```
composer why-not typo3/cms-core 11.5.32
```

generates this:

```
typo3/cms-core                 v11.5.32 requires         egulias/email-validator (^3.2.1)           
__root__                       -        requires         egulias/email-validator (^2.1)             
typo3/cms-core                 v11.5.32 requires         guzzlehttp/guzzle (^7.7.0)                 
__root__                       -        does not require guzzlehttp/guzzle (but 6.5.8 is installed) 
typo3/cms-core                 v11.5.32 requires         guzzlehttp/psr7 (^2.4.3)                   
__root__                       -        does not require guzzlehttp/psr7 (but 1.9.1 is installed)   
typo3/cms-core                 v11.5.32 requires         typo3/cms-cli (^3.1)                       
__root__                       -        does not require typo3/cms-cli (but 2.0.0 is installed)
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 0):

Composer already tells you what the issue is, but let's examine this together. But before we start, one hint:

`composer update` allows to specify packages to update, but only in the already set and allowed version constraints. It does not know the semantic of a version.

That means, that you need to use `composer require` to change the version constraint of a package or a couple of package to a installable mix.

You already tried that, but failed by getting 3 problems stated. Let's go through them in the "order" which makes sense.

```
Problem 2
    - typo3/cms-base-distribution is locked to version v10.4.3 and
      an update of this package was not requested.
    - typo3/cms-base-distribution v10.4.3 requires typo3/cms-core ^10.4.0
      -> found typo3/cms-core[v10.4.0, ..., v10.4.37] but it conflicts with
      your temporary update constraint (typo3/cms-core:11.5.32).
```

It tells you, that `typo3/cms-base-distribution` is locked to version 10.4.3. This packages requires TYPO3 v10 and dies not allow other TYPO3 core versions. Therefore, it conflicts with your request to use `typo3/cms-core:^.5.32).

The package itselfe is not raised. Looking into your composer.json, we find following constraint:

```
"typo3/cms-base-distribution": "^10.4",
```

Which loks this particular packagte to "> 10.4.0 < 11.0.0" versions, and therefore also for typo3/cms-*  core packages.

An upgrade of this package has not been requested.

You need to require all packages in a version which plays neat together.

But that's not all, we can directly see another issue:

```
Problem 3
    - typo3/cms-extbase is locked to version v10.4.37 and an update of
      this package was not requested.
    - typo3/cms-extbase v10.4.37 requires typo3/cms-core 10.4.37
      -> found typo3/cms-core[v10.4.37] but it conflicts with your
      temporary update constraint (typo3/cms-core:11.5.32).
```

That tells us, that `typo3/cms-extbase` is locked to a 10er version and a upgrade to a 11 is not requested - and therefore conflicts with the require of `typo3/cms-core` as a 11er version. The `-W` flag does not help here, as it would only installs newer versions allowed by the constraints - which is not possible if we look into your composer.json again.

```
        "typo3/cms-core": "^10.4 || 11.*",
        "typo3/cms-extbase": "^10.4 || 11.*"
```

Your project `root composer.json` directly requires two TYPO3 core system extension packages - core and extbase. The other mandantory system extensions are required `indirectly` by the `typo3/cms-base-distribution` package.

The first problem

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires typo3/cms-core ^10.4 || 11.*,
      found typo3/cms-core[v10.4.0, ..., v10.4.37, v11.0.0, ..., v11.5.32]
      but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another
      require.
```

simly tells us, that the request package version constraint change cannot be fullfilled because of other packages - which are listed as follow up problems  ( 2 + 3 ).

Putting this together, we need to do following to solve this issue:

- raise direct `typo3/cms-*` packages to a ^11.5 constraint

or to speak in a command, following should do the trick in this case:

```
composer require -W \
  "typo3/cms-base-distribution":"^11.5" \
  "typo3/cms-core":"^11.5" \
  "typo3/cms-extbase":"^11.5"
```

`typo3/cms-base-distribution` is not a TYPO3 system extension direcetly. It's a meta composer package which contains constraints of system extension packages used for most basic projects and systems - not a bare minimum, more a "usual used" constellation.

You need to thing of dependencies change, as this removes some selected system packages from your root compose.json.

However, some people prefers to avoid such meta package and directly requiring all system extensions directly in the project `root composer.json`.

You can find a helper to select through system packages available in a corresponding TYPO3 major core version, as some packages are dropped or new one are added. For example, TYPO3 v12 introduced two new system extensions - and others have been phased out/removed from the core like for example the old "func" system extensions and others.

You can find that helper as a "click" helper here: [`TYPO3 composer helper` [1]](https://get.typo3.org/misc/composer/helper)

You can use following command:

```
composer info | grep 'typo3/cms-'
```

to get a list of installed system extensions. Use the helper for the v11 version and click all named system extension. That will output your composer require command to use to change the constraints.

In your case, you would need to remove the base distribution package and require the core extensions directly:

```
composer remove --no-install \
  "typo3/cms-base-distribution"

composer require -W \
    typo3/cms-backend:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-belog:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-beuser:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-core:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-dashboard:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-extbase:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-extensionmanager:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-felogin:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-filelist:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-fluid:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-form:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-frontend:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-impexp:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-info:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-install:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-recordlist:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-seo:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-setup:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-sys-note:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-t3editor:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-tstemplate:^11.5 \
    typo3/cms-viewpage:^11.5
```

You could also use patchlevel versions to ensure that you have the current versions as minimum for the v11 version, but using the `11.5` is mostly enough and combined with having a composer.lock file committed in yout vcs (git) you can use

```
composer update -W typo3/cms-*
```

To update the system extensions along with dependencies, but only for the allowed TYPO3 core version.

For project, normaly allowing multiple version per package is not a casual practice (for system extensions). That may be different for extension composer.json files.

**Links**

- [1] `TYPO3 composer helper` https://get.typo3.org/misc/composer/helper

Answer (score -1):

try a `composer why-not typo3/cms-core 11.5.32` the why/why-not are usually better at explaining what is gooing on. ususally some dependency is not met like a missing php-extension, php version, or other composer extension beeing not compatible with v11

Comment: thank you
i get this message  Not enough arguments (missing: "version").

Comment: Please use a space between package name and version, not `:`.

Comment: I dont know what you mean
thats what I did

Answer (score -1):

You need to update all your packages in one go. For the TYPO3 core packages you can use the [TYPO3 composer helper](https://get.typo3.org/misc/composer/helper) to generate the necessary composer command.

You need to make sure that all `typo3/cms-*` packages are still available in v11. If not, you need to remove them before the upgrade.

Then you need to extend the above generated composer command with the extensions you want to have, e.g. `georgringer/news:^11.2`. For each extension you need to specify a version that is compatible with TYPO3 v11.

And last but not least you should add the flag `-W` to your composer command to update also all other dependencies of your packages.

If one of your extension is maybe custom made and not yet compatible with TYPO3 v11, you should remove it before the upgrade. Then update the extension and require it again.

Comment: used the composer helper  > still the same "conflicts with another require" >
third-party TYPO3 Extension are off > 
what about: 
doctrine/annotations           
doctrine/dbal                  
doctrine/lexer                 
egulias/email-validator        
enshrined/svg-sanitize         
guzzlehttp/guzzle              
guzzlehttp/promises            
guzzlehttp/psr7                
helhum/typo3-console           
psr/container                  
psr/http-message               

>> they are listed as outdated
do I have to update them separatly?

Comment: No that should be covered by the `--update-with-all-dependencies (-W)` flag. You need to check every package which is listed in the require section of your root composer.json.